# Bootstrap tooltip doesn't work on my div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This might just be to do with how I set up the page, but here goes:

I'm trying to apply Bootstraps default tooltip to some div elements I got. But it doesn't work for some reason. When my page is done loading I run this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();
    GetActivityAbstracts();
    CheckDatetimePickersValidity();
    CreateColumnDescriptions();
    CreateFilterDropdown();
});
```

The content that needs to be affected by the Tooltip is made in this function as you can see is called above:

```
function GetActivityAbstracts() {
    $.getJSON("", function (testData) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(testData);
        var activityTable = '<tbody></tbody>';
        $.each(object, function () {
            var activityId = this['ActivityId'];
            var activityName = this['ActivityName'];
            var activityResponsible = this['Responsible'];
            var activityEstimatedSavings = parseFloat(this['EstimatedSavings']).toFixed(2);
            var activityEstimatedStart = this['EstimatedStart'];
            var activityEstimatedEnd = this['EstimatedEnd'];
            var activityStatus = this['Status'];
            // TODO: Make more user-friendly Status Descriptions instead of C# enum values.
            var tableElement =
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle; align: center;">'
                    + activityId + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">' +
                    '<div class="status-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"' +
                    'title=" ' + activityStatus + '" style="background-color:' +
                    GetColumnColor(activityStatus) + ';"></div></td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityName + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityResponsible + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedSavings + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedStart + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedEnd + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            activityTable += tableElement;
        });
        $('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);
    });
}
```

Now the HTML comes out just fine but the actual tooltip seems to be the default windows one:

[image]

And I have tested that the tooltips work at all. I have a modal window here where they work just fine:

[image]

Here is the styling for the Circle:

```
.status-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* Don't question it */
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Check whether the bootstrap.min.js file included or not? Share your html content to get clarity and let someone help you!

Comment: @AntonySUTHAKARJ If `bootstrap.min.js` will be missing the code will not execute further since it will fail in the first line `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();` that `undefined is not a function`. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();` after you appended your data like:

```
$('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();
```

This is because, you are inserting your HTML content dynamically and your call to bootstrap `tooltip()` function is done before so the tooltip is not getting initialized on new elements.

Comment: Ah right. I knew it had something to do with the dynamically generated content hah. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Shashank Agrawal, your code is missing to the closing square bracket.

Correction:

```
$('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```